# CakePHP 2.7 save() failing with a single empty key in validationErrors

Tags: php, cakephp

Basically, I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
$this->ModelName->id = $id;
$this->ModelName->save(
    array('ModelName'=>array(
        'boolean_column1'=>1,
        'boolean_column2'=>0,
        'string_column'=>'Some short string[always the same]'
)));
```

Sometimes this save fails. So I added the following:

```
debug($this->ModelName->validationErrors);
debug($this->ModelName->invalidFields());
```

And the results are:

```
########## DEBUG ##########
array(
    (int) 0 => array()
)
###########################
########## DEBUG ##########
array(
    (int) 0 => array()
)
###########################
```

When I set the "validate" param to false then this doesn't happen. I have also tried changing the save array in a way that doesn't have the 'ModelName' key, but it didn't help.

There aren't any beforeSave or afterSave callbacks, nor is there a $validate setting in this Model. There are more fields then there are being saved in this call, but this is updating an existing row in the database table.

This is code that runs cyclically in a Queue as part of an hour long cron job. I'm seeing different behaviours on different runs, which could be due to other queued functions changing something that causes issues, but I'm not seeing it, and it's difficult to find without a readable error message. This started happening after upgrading to 2.7.0 from 2.4.x and has worked fine since 1.3.x.

**UPDATE 1**: Ok, so I've updated the Model.php file to the version in the unreleased 2.8 branch, which includes a bugfix for 'atomic', and it's working now. If I manage to find out what was causing it precisely, I'll update here.

Comment: Please use real names, your model is _not_ called Model (or if it is, that's problematic) and using that name is confusing.

Comment: It would be advisable to show us the code so we can help rather than assume that changing stuff around makes it just as easy.

Comment: @AD7six, fair enough. I've replaced it with "ModelName" which should make more sense.

Comment: @MattStephens this is part of a big codebase which I really can't all paste in here. These are the lines I've narrowed the issue down to, and I'm currently putting var_dumps within the Cake core to see where it fails to validate exactly. Also, I'm goint to try updating to 2.8.x to see if that changes anything, and report back.

Comment: @NickZinger The problem is that it might not be where you have narrowed it down too, no offence but sometimes as a developer you can overlook things. Are those 3 fields the only ones being saved there?

Comment: @MattStephens, non taken. I know what you mean, and I've spent a great deal of time looking at what might the issue be. Beyond explaining what some 300 lines of code do in my system I don't see pasting more code as a solution. Yes, those are the only 3 fields being saved. What's more, some times the save works, if this is the first function called.

Comment: See update. I can only tag one of you sooo @AD7six

Comment: This is the commit that fixed it for me https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/c6e5026767e07585d43ff63de397535d652c18cc . Adding as answer.

Comment: Please _stop_ making up the names of your classes - it's not called ModelName and its not in a file called `Model.php` either.

Comment: @AD7six, actually it is Model.php this time. I was talking about the Cake source - check the commit link. But point taken for making up names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I added this commit from the (at this moment) unreleased 2.8 branch which fixed it:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/c6e5026767e07585d43ff63de397535d652c18cc

From the commit message:

> Fix issues saveMany & saveAssociated with boolean values. 
>   For non-atomic, save operations that include models with boolean
>   fields. The first false value would cause the save to abort. This
>   regression was introduced in [#6947](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/5b31eff00cf1892a48ddd8e768eb6af0ddba06ff). Instead of checking the data
>   from save() we should be boolean casting save() to capture the
>   success/failure.